# Windows Server 2008 R2 Time Stops

Tags: windows, freeze, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, time

I have a recently re-imaged tower server running Windows Server 2008 R2 that is "freezing" time.

After booting up the server, everything is working fine. I click on the time in the task bar and open the calendar/clock applet, and the computer time works as I would expect.  But after ~20 minutes of not using the mouse/keyboard, the seconds and minutes stop counting up, time "freezes".  The machine is not asleep or on stand-by, the screen is on. After moving the mouse again though, be it 5 minutes or 5 hours after it freezes, the time starts counting up again where it left off.

We have a logging utility on the machine that creates a log file with timestamp every 10 seconds, and when time is frozen, it creates logs with the exact same timestamp over and over until time resumes.

Everything I've come across has been time issues while the computer is asleep, in power saving mode or incorrect times after being shut off, but this has me stumped.

I have Re-registered the Windows time service, run sfc and performed Windows updates for what it's worth, with no results.

Comment: What CPU(s) does the server have?

Comment: its an older machine running a single Intel Xeon E3-1270

Comment: Does it have CMOS (and so CMOS battery)?

Comment: Yes, the battery is new, replace just 2 months ago when it was installed.

Comment: Server 2008 is pretty much dead. You may need to get the server looked at by a repair shop.  See first if this is worth it.

Comment: We can't exactly take it out of production, the upgrade window for this machine is still 4 months away, downtime only happens twice a year.  Taking it somewhere would mean ~200-300k/hr losses.  there have been thoughts about getting a mouse jiggler though to keep it alive

Comment: Is this a fresh reinstall; does it have all the drivers installed? As a workaround, what happens if you turn off the CPU power-saving states in system BIOS? (There aren't any Scheduled Tasks somebody left in it as a prank, are there?)